# Como "desenhar" um composable encima do app bar?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Seguinte quero fazer algo nesse esquema da imagem, na verdade ja fiz usando algumas boxes e ajustando com padding, minha duvida é: Eu consigo fazer isso de uma maneira melhor?
Se tiverem alguma dica ou palavra chave para eu pesquisar sobre o assunto...

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: Eu tinha anexado uma imagem, mas acho que deu erro